# How to find a special bookmark and edit the text

Tags: google-docs-api, bookmarks

i create some bookmarks in my Google Docs with this script:

```
function myFunctionCreate() {
   var mydoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
   var cursor = mydoc.getCursor();
   var bookmark = mydoc.addBookmark(cursor);
   Logger.log(bookmark.getId());
 }
```

How can i jump to this bookmarks and edit the text?

Can I also target a bookmark?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the [`getPosition()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/bookmark#getposition). `Gets the` [`Position`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position.html) `of the Bookmark within the` [`Document`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document.html).`

Comment: It is to strange for me. Here is my example: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/149BmBtXW-nqinhj4Kft8HeO1RaQ9QrYiKu78Dmi87oE/edit?usp=sharing). My intention is to jump about a menuepoint to a bookmark. Please have a quick look on my Script - when it is ok for you.